# Tetris and pretty graphics

Tags: model-view-controller, graphics, encapsulation

Say you're building a Tetris game. As any proper programmer, you have your view logic on one side, and your business logic on the other side; probably a full-on MVC going on.

When the model sends its `update()`, the view redraws itself, as expected.

But then... if you wanted to add, say, an animation to vanish a line, how would you implement that in the view?

Make any assumptions you want---excepting that "Everything is properly encapsulated".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I would separate draw the screen as often as possible, even if there was no update of the block position. So I would have a loop somewhere with an **"update"** and a **"render"** part. Update plays the ball to the logic which does or does not any update of positions and/or block removal. Render plays the ball to the graphics part, which draws the blocks where they should be.

Now if there are lines to erase, the logic knows and can mark those lines to be removed. I assume here, that every piece consists of 4 single blocks and any of these blocks is a single object. Now when this block has the "die"-flag set, you may take some render-parts to vanish the block (let's say, 500ms to explode). After this time, the object may be disposed and the block a line above falls down. Why 500ms? Well, you should definitely use **time-based movement** as this keeps the game speed the same on different computers.

Btw, there are already so called game engines which provide such an update-render-loop. For example XNA, if you go the .NET line. You may also code your own engine but beware, it's not an easy task and it's very time consuming. I did this once and don't expect it to be an engine like the Source Engine ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Most games execute a loop that constantly redraws the view of the game as fast as possible, rather than waiting for a change in the model state and then refreshing the view.

If you like the model view pattern, then it might work well for the view to continue to draw some types of objects after they are removed from the model, fading them out over a few milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to combine class MVC with something like differential execution - the 'view' is a model of what is presented, but the drawing code compares the stream of events the 'view' creates with the stream from the previous rendering. So if in one stream there's a line, and the next there isn't, the drawing code can animate the difference. This allows the drawing to be abstracted away from the view . Frequently the 'view' in MVC is a collection of widgets, rather than being something which draws the display directly, so you end up with nested MVC hierarchies anyway: the application is MVC ( data model, view objects, app controller ), where the view object has a collection of widgets each of which is MVC ( widget state (eg button pressed ), look and feel/toolkit binding, mapping of toolkit events -> widget state ).

Answer (score 1):

I've often wondered this myself.

My own thoughts have been along this line:

1) The view is given the state of the blocks (shape, yada-yada), but with extra "transitional" data:

2) The fact that a line must be removed is encoded in the state, NOT computed in the view.

3) The view knows how to draw transitions now:

- No change: state is the same for this particular block
- Change from "falling" to "locked": state is "locked in" (by a dropping block)
- Change from "locked" to "remove": state is "removed" (by a line completion)
- Change from "falling" to "remove": state is "removed", but old state was "falling"

Answer (score 1):

Its interesting to think of a game as an MVC. Thats a perspective I've never taken (for some odd reason), but definitely an intriguing one that makes a lot of sense. Assuming you do implement your Tetris game with an MVC, I think there are two things you might want to take into account in regards to communication between your controller and your view: There is state, and there are events.

Your controller is obviously the central point of interaction for the user. When they issue keyboard commands, your controller will interpret them, and make the appropriate state adjustments. However, sometimes the game will enter a state that coincides with a particular event...such as filling a line with blocks that should now be removed.

Scoregraphic has given you a great foundation. Your view should operate on a fixed cycle to maintain consistent speed across computers. But in addition to updating the screen to render new state, it should also have a queue of events that it can perform animations in response to. In the case of filling lines in Tetris, your controller could issue strongly typed event objects that derive from some kind of base event type into the view event queue, which could then be used by the view to perform the appropriate animated responses.